# TypeError: Enemy() takes no arguments I've been getting this error repeatedly

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

[ The enemy constructor doesn't take arguments and i've check init which has two underscores as in **init** what else is my mistake?

```
File "c:/Users/Tharun/Documents/RPG.py", line 17, in <module>
    enemy1 = Enemy(40, 49)
TypeError: Enemy() takes no arguments
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYgMY.png)

Comment: Check the Image I've attached  https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYgMY.png

Comment: Post your code as text. Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please paste your code instead of images. It makes debugging a lot easier for us. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You identation is wrong. You are defining a function **init** outside of the class like

```py
class A:
    a = 1

def __init__:
    pass
```

while what you want is:

```py
 class A:
    a = 1

    def __init__:
        pass
```